# Grouping similar strings from different rows and counting the total in R

Tags: r, pivot-table

I have a table that looks like this:

| League | Team | Coach |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Summer | Rangers1-North | Tiffany |
| Winter | Rangers2 | James |
| Summer | Ranger1-South | Tiffany |

I need to perform some sort of group_by and combine the similar rows (Rangers1-North, Ranger1-South) into one complete row for the correct coach and league with a total amount for numbers of teams to look like this: Table with subset of rows. Please see the image down below

[image]

so it is essentially a pivot table. I'm struggling with this very much. Any help would be much appreciated, I have very little R skills.

Comment: How do you determine that the first row of the output table should have "Tiffany" as the coach and 2 as the count? (the two "Rangers1-x" rows in the input have different coaches ...)

Comment: Thank you for that. I made the correction. It is for few assignments at work my team is working on. We are using R to do it.

Comment: @BenBolker that's my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the data clean enough to guarantee that Rangers1-North and Rangers1-South will always have the same coach? And is it the case that there is always Team-Other Information?

If so (this is far more verbose than necessary, but it seems like you're new to R, so hopefully it's easier to follow)

```
library(data.table)

#Your data
data <- data.table(league = c("summer", "winter", "summer"), 
                   team = c("Rangers1-North", "Rangers2", "Rangers1-South"),
                   coach = c("Tiffany", "James", "Tiffany"))

#Creates the team name
data[, team_subset := gsub("(.*)-.*", "\\1", team)]

#Generates your count variable
data[, count := .N, by=c("team_subset", "league", "coach")]

#For non-subset firms, delete subset
data[count == 1, team_subset := ""]

#Subsets the data and retains unique items
tmp <- unique(data[count > 1], by=c("team_subset", "league", "coach"))
tmp[, `:=` (team = team_subset, team_subset = "")]

#Recombine and sort
data <- rbind(data, tmp)
setorder(data, team, league)
data <- data[order(team), .(team, team_subset, league, coach, count)]
```

Comment: This is great however it doesn't pivot the table to make it display as in the photo. Yes, Rangers1-North and Rangers1-South will always have the same coach; that won't change. There is no Team-Other information. Your is so helpful! Just one thing, we would need it to count only 1 for each team and then the total at top. Yours display that total count for each team.

Comment: So, I didn't know there was pivot table functionality in R (not sure why I'm surprised). There's a package called pivottabler that you can look into that should create the specific image you're looking for. Documentation is here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pivottabler/vignettes/v00-vignettes.html

Comment: You've now gotten a nearly complete solution, for only the effort on your part of asking the question.  Can you figure out how to adapt the answer given?